# Unity C# UnassignedReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When i run

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovment : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb.useGravity = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

it gives me

```
UnassignedReferenceException: The variable rb of PlayerMovment has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the rb variable of the PlayerMovment script in the inspector.
PlayerMovment.Start ()
```

I rewrote the script couple of times but it gives the the same error. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the rigidbody. Assuming there is a rigidbody component on the same game object that has the script.

```
   void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.useGravity = false;
    }
```